# Automapper 5.0 global configuration

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

I am using the code below in `AutoMapperConfig.cs`  in `App_Start` folder. I
initialized it in `Global.asax`  as  `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure()`

But I am unable to use the `Mapper.Map<Hospital, MongoHospital>` in my
controller. It is throwing an exception that no mappings are defined.  It
was working in previous versions of Automapper which were supporting
`Mapper.CreateMap<>` methods.  I am confused how to use
`MapperConfiguration` instance.

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile<HospitalProfile>();
                }
        );
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}

public class HospitalProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Hospital, MongoHospital>()
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString()));
                });
        config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

Trying to access this map as below

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Hospital>, IEnumerable<MongoHospital>>(hospitalsOnDB);
```

Comment: Your profile should be calling CreateMap, not creating whole config object.

Comment: What is the use of MapperConfiguration ? Where does it fit perfectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need to use a Profile in this scenario? If you don't, you can try just initialising the Mapper like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<Hospital, MongoHospital>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString()));
            });
    }
}
```

However, if you would like to still register a Profile, you can do this:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<HospitalProfile>();
            }
        );
    }
}

public class HospitalProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Hospital, MongoHospital>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. If you're using AutoMapper 5.0, remember that this is still at beta-1 at this point in time.

Comment: This solution works. But i am just wondering what is the purpose of MapperConfiguration class?  Where does it be useful?

Comment: I think AutoMapper has always supported it's static implementation of a Mapper, as used above - it's registered/initialised once per AppDomain and can be referenced through the static Mapper class. The configuration approach allows an IMapper to be configured and registered on a container for dependency injection purposes. That may not be 100% correct, but that's my understanding.

Comment: Yep that's pretty much it. Or if you want to provide a segmented config, say a shared library provides some config etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with AutoMapper 5.2.

Your Profile class as below

```
public class MapperProfile: Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Hospital, MongoHospital>().ReverseMap();
    }

}
```

Then in your Global.asax

```
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
       //Rest of the code 
       Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfiles(new string[] { "DLL NAME OF YOUR PROFILE CLASS" }));
     }
```

Now when you need to create an instance

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Instance.Map<MongoHospital, Hospital>(source, new Hospital());
```

Hope this helps.